Want to add API response to eclipse code editor temporarily and once click outside temporarily portion Api response should disappear
I am using the below code to write Api response in eclipse code editor.
StyleText textWiget =(StyleText) textEditor.getAdapter(Control.class);
textWiget.replaceTextRange(insertOffset, 0, apiResponse);

This is part of the code and i am able to write text in code editor.
But, now i want this API response code to appear in eclipse code editor temporarily and once click anywhere outside temporarily portion it should disappear from eclipse code editor.
How can i implement it programmatically?
Please explain with code example.
I have tried this code
StyleText textWiget =(StyleText) textEditor.getAdapter(Control.class);
textWiget.replaceTextRange(insertOffset, 0, apiResponse);

to write Api response code just below the selected code in eclipse code editor.
But since i am new to eclipse plugin development, so i don't have any idea how to write api response in eclipse code editor temporarily and it should disappear once click anywhere outside temporary section in eclipse code editor.
I need assistance for this.

You can't just write in to the StyledText like that, it will completely mess up the editor's knowledge of the document. You must use the APIs provided by the various editors to interact with them. This will generally mean using the extension points provided.
